# Synchronize RTSP with computer time

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp, libav

I am successfully using libav to receive the video stream from an RTSP network source. The point is that I need to syncronize my computer's time with the video capturing, meaning that I need to know which datetime of my computer corresponds to the first frame (pts = 0). My API calls are the following ones:

```
av_register_all()
avcodec_register_all()
avformat_network_init()
avformat_open_input()
avformat_find_stream_info()
av_read_play()
loop
  av_init_packet()
  av_read_frame()
  [...]
  av_free_packet
end loop
```

With the calls above, I successfully read frames, but I do need to know how can I know the exact absolute datetime that corresponds to the first frame, since it has a pts of 0. Maybe I can use a time() function or GetSystemTime (I am using Windows) between two calls of the above, but do not really know how libav works.